# Can course of the moving vehicle determine if the vehicle is moving left or right?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm using the Core Location Framework from apple.

I need to know if `CLLocationDirection` (course of the GPS) is the way to determine whether the moving vehicle is turning left or right or going straight ? If so, how ?

If not, is there another feature of the framework better suited to identifying turns?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a differential GPS problem.  While stationary you don't even know what direction it's facing.  Given two positions you can get a heading.  Given three you can get a turn.  All of that can easily be fouled by natural statistical error in the position reported vs the actual position.  You'll have to decide at what distance you trust that you're seeing a real change in position.

Comment: Can anyone tell me with respect to which axis is the course value to be considered ? let's say if the course is 174 degrees, how can I interpret the value ?

Comment: CLLocationDirection Represents a direction that is measured in degrees relative to true north that increases in value clockwise.

Comment: Well since they refuse to remove the hold I'll try to help you here.  The answer is time.  Record directions over time.  Changes in directions over time are turns.  Again statistical error will create a level of noise you will need a threshold to filter.  This is what you need to spot if the vehicle IS turning.  If all you need to know is if you've missed a turn just check if location and direction is still match the route.

Comment: Just think about an x-y grid. Any line, in any direction, at any offset represents a 'straight path' (ie: no turning). It will be in the form of `y = mx + c`. By definition, there is no second derivative, ie `d^2y/dx^2 = 0`. Therefore, a non 'straight-path' has `d^2y/dx^2 != 0`.

Comment: @CandiedOrange You do actually get a heading (i.e. direction) field with a location. You just need two to tell which direction the user is turning.

Comment: @Kevin Yeah I know.  Get two headings, call them `oldHeading` and `newHeading`.  newHeading - oldHeading will tell you the change in heading.  It'll be positive for right turns and negative for left turns.  Divide it by the difference in time and you get the rate of change.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments `CLLocationDirection` can work for this if you use it over time.

That said, it's not without issues.  `newHeading - oldHeading` will be positive for right turns and negative for left turns but only when the two headings don't find them selves on either side of north.

Going from 355 to 5 should give a +10Deg (right turn).  So you have a corner case to resolve.

The basic assumption you have to make is that the turn happened over the smaller angle.  Which will be true if the data collection rate is reasonable and the car isn't tumbling over a cliff.  If it is I doubt the passengers will care if the GPS gets confused.

objective-c might have a more elegant way to calculate this but my java polluted brain see's it as:

```
// Some test data
//   deltaH newH oldH             expected
//    -350 = 5 - 355 should return +10
//    -355 = 0 - 355 should return +5
//       5 = 5 - 0 should return +5
//     -10 = 5 - 15 should return -10
//      10 = 15 - 5 should return 10
//    -181 = 0 - 181 should return 179
//     181 = 181 - 0 should return -179
//    
int deltaH = newH - oldH;

//Ensure deltaH takes the shortest path from oldH to newH
if ( -180 < deltaH && deltaH < 180 )  {
    return deltaH;
} else if (deltaH <= -180) {
    return deltaH + 360;
} else if (deltaH >= 180) {
    return deltaH - 360;
} else {
    throw new AssertionError("Logic error");
}
```

I'm sure there's a way translate that into objective-c.

Another issue is precision loss.  If CLLocationDirection is calculated from a more raw data source, say GPS positional data, then it is very likely that whatever calculates CLLocationDirection is lossy.  Meaning it should be possible to get more accurate results by going back to the raw data and calculating turn direction from that.  When calculating derivatives this stuff becomes important.